# MOV instruction between 16 and 8 bits in my code

Tags: assembly, x86

I just started learning Assembly Lagrange and I need some helps.

For the following instructions:
1- Can I use MOV between different registers size?
2- In the last line, how AX became 47AFH?

Let assume the address 2000H contains 47H and 2001H contains AFH

```
MOV BX, 2000H   ;load BX with address
MOV AL, [BX]    ;places 47H into AL
MOV AX, [BX]    ;places 47AFH into AX
```

Comment: 1) That doesn't happen in this code. 2) It didn't. Based on your description, AX's value would become AF47H.

Comment: 1) you can't. There are special instructions `movzx` and `movsx`, and various other arithmetic means, how to deal with such situation, for example common way how to extend `setCC` result to 32 bits is: `xor eax,eax` `<set ZF somehow as you wish>` `setz al` => `eax` is now 0 or 1 according to ZF. (and `setz al` `movzx eax,al` will do the same ... and there are surely many other ways...).

Comment: What architecture is this? Please tag x86 if it's x86.

Comment: So, in the second line, BX is 16 bit and AL 8 bit they are different sizes, right? For the last line , I don't get it?

Comment: [BX] means data from address stored in BX. Size of this register does not matter here. Same way [EBX] in 64bit mode can point to 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 or 32 bytes.

Comment: The `[bx]` says you want value from memory, with first byte starting at address from `bx`. It doesn't say how big value you want. That's deduced from the `al` usage, so only 1 byte will be read from memory. It's problem with immediate values, when you write in ASM `mov [bx],1`, you must specify the size of the immediate, how many bytes should be written into memory, like `mov word ptr [bx],1` in TASM/MASM or `mov [bx], word 1` in NASM.

Comment: What about the last line. How the AX became 47AFH while the DX still has the same value in both last two lines?

Comment: `ax` will not become `0x47AF`. Try it in debugger. It will become `0xAF47`. It will again load value from memory, from the same address `bx`, but this time the deduced size from `ax` is 16 bit, so it will load two bytes from memory. Memory contains `0x47, 0xAF`, which is word value `0xAF47`.

Comment: So ,  if I add "MOV   AL, 0" before last line, the result of the last will be 0AFH, right?

Comment: No, @AymanAlghamdi.  How many bits is AL and how many bits is "0x0A"?

Comment: `mov ax,0xAF47` `mov al,0` => `ax == 0xAF00`. In hexadecimal formatting every digit `0-F` is exactly 4 bits, so `0xABCD` => high 8 bits are set to value `AB` (binary `1010 1011`), lower 8 bits are `CD` (binary `1100 1101`). When you put 16 bit value `0xABCD` into `ax/bx/cx/dx`, then the `ah/bh/ch/dh` contains the upper 8 bits `0xAB`, and `al/bl/cl/dl` contains the lower 8 bits of value `0xCD`. In memory the value is stored in little-endian, storing least significant byte first, so `mov [0x2000],ax` with `ax=0xABCD` will set memory byte at 0x2000 to `0xCD`, and byte at 0x2001 to `0xAB`.